# Understanding the Output of anova() in R

Tags: r, anova, dataset

```
> anova(fit4,fit3)
Analysis of Variance Table
Model 1: Y ~ SNP7 + SNP8 + SNP14
Model 2: Y ~ SNP2 + SNP4 + SNP7 + SNP8 + SNP14
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1    996 1048.5                           
2    994 1045.9  2    2.5346 1.2044 0.3003
```

I am not sure how to interpret `Pr(>F)` value. What is the null hypothesis?
Is it `H0: Beta2 = Beta4 = 0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your null hypothesis H0 is correct. Indeed, here anova says that Model2 (the more complicated) is not significantly better than Model1. In other words, there isn't enough evidence to reject H0: beta2=beta4=0 because the p-value is equal to 0.3003.